# Getting value of selected item in list box as string

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I am trying to get the value of the selected item in the listbox using the code below, but it is always returning null string.

```
DataSet ds = searchforPrice(Convert.ToString(listBox1.SelectedItem));
```

Here I am trying to pass the value of selected item as string to method searchforPrice to retrive dataset from the database.

How can i retrive the value of selected item as string?

I am adding items to listbox from combo box which in turn loads the items from the database.

```
 listBox1.Items.Add(comboBox2.Text);
```

[image]

Anybody has answer for this..

Comment: Please post the code that loads the list box.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the display text of the item, use the [`GetItemText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext.aspx) method:

```
string text = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: @AmritSharma, did you check that `SelectedItem` is not null?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque check the Screenshot above

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, yes the selectedItem value is null

Comment: @AmritSharma, OK, so there is nothing selected in the ListBox. So why do you expect to get a meaningful result? It doesn't really make sense to me...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, I do select I item and it does successfully delete but I don't get the string out of it. May be the sequence of delete is wrong so that, it is coming null

Comment: You need to access SelectedItem before you delete the item, otherwise it will return null

Comment: GetItemText  method  is not  available...please  help...iam  developing  windows phone   application

Comment: Bad answer.  I am using Visual Studio 17.  There is no method or value for a listbox named "GetItemText".  Just doesn't exist in my version.  What now?  " 'ListBox' does not contain a definition for 'GetItemText' " is the error message.  It doesn't even compile.  I am at the WTF where the F is Frustration.  List Box should be very easy and it seems impossible.

Comment: @BaruchAtta `GetItemText` definitely [exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_ListControl_GetItemText_System_Object_) (inherited from `ListControl`). My guess is that you're not using Windows Forms, but perhaps WPF or UWP, which have different ListBox controls.

Comment: Thomas Levesque - My correct answer is string text = ((sender as ListBox)?.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem)?.Content.ToString();  // correct answer - and GetItemText raises an error.  It does not compile.  The error message is "ListBox does not contain a definition for GetItemText..."  A correct answer would compile, no?  I am using C# in Visual Studio 17.  Are you using a previous version?

Comment: @BaruchAtta did you read my comment? You're not using the same UI framework my answer applies to. The question is about Windows Forms (`winforms` in tags), and this answer applies to Windows Forms, which definitely has the GetItemText method. If you're using another UI framework such as WPF or UWP, the answer doesn't apply. The fact that you're using VS2017 doesn't say anything about which UI framework you're using, since several exist.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using ListBox in your application and you want to return the selected value of ListBox and display it in a Label or any thing else then use this code, it will help you

```
 private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         label1.Text  = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: have tried the code you have suggested, the string that it is outputting is: System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem: AndThenTheActualString - how does one get rid of the lengthy system.windows - which noone wants to see?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon the answer works with ListBox. Your code was using ListView, and that is why there's "System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem" there.

Answer (score 1):

To retreive the value of all selected item in à listbox you can cast selected item in DataRowView and then select column where your data is:

```
foreach(object element in listbox.SelectedItems) {
    DataRowView row = (DataRowView)element;
    MessageBox.Show(row[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string textValue = ((ListBoxItem)listBox1.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `as` like this. It make look cleaner, but it's malformed. `as` is for checking whether an object is a certain type. You're using the wrong tools for the job. It's best to cast it properly `((ListBoxItem)listBox1.SelectedItem)`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation PC Luddite, shall correct it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve your value from an list box
you should try this:

```
String itemSelected = numberListBox.GetItemText(numberListBox.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: GetItemText  
method is not available...please help...iam  developing windows phone application

Answer (score 0):

Get FullName in ListBox of files (full path) list (Thomas Levesque answer modificaton, thanks Thomas):

```
...
        string tmpStr = "";
        foreach (var item in listBoxFiles.SelectedItems)
        {
            tmpStr += listBoxFiles.GetItemText(item) + "\n";
        }
        MessageBox.Show(tmpStr);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use This One To get the selected ListItme Name ::

```
String selectedItem = ((ListBoxItem)ListBox.SelectedItem).Name.ToString();
```

Make sure that Your each ListBoxItem have a Name property

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on previous answer by Pir Fahim, he's right but i'm using selectedItem.Text (only way to make it work to me)

Use the SelectedIndexChanged() event to store the data somewhere.
In my case, i usually fill a custom class, something like:

```
class myItem {
    string name {get; set;}
    string price {get; set;}
    string desc {get; set;}
}

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     myItem selected_item = new myItem();
     selected_item.name  = listBox1.SelectedItem.Text;
     Retrieve (selected_item.name);
}
```

And then you can retrieve the rest of data from a List of "myItems"..

```
myItem Retrieve (string wanted_item) {
    foreach (myItem item in my_items_list) {
        if (item.name == wanted_item) {
               // This is the selected item
               return item; 
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct solution seems to be:

`string text = ((ListBoxItem)ListBox1.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();`

Please be sure to use **.Content** and not **.Name**.

Answer (score -1):

set  properties listbox1 DisplayMember = "Text";
set  properties listbox1 ValueMember = "Value";

Event

```
    private void listbox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedValue = listbox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to retrieve the item selected from listbox, here is the code...

```
String SelectedItem = listBox1.SelectedItem.Value;
```

Comment: listBox1.SelectedItem.Value; // the .Value portion at the and of listBox1.SelectedItem doesn't seem to be showing up in my IDE. any pointers?

Comment: SelectedItem has no property "Value"