# How to get listbox selected item value

Tags: c#, listbox

I am working with C# .NET 4.0

I am trying to get the value of a single selected item in a listbox.

This is how I populate the control:

```
this.files_lb.DataSource = DataTable object
```

In my designer, I have specified file_name as the DisplayMember and file_id as the DisplayValue

After selecting an item in the listbox, I tried the following to get the value:

```
this.files_lb.SelectedValue.ToString()
```

But all it returns is `"System.Data.DataRowView".`

At this link : [Getting value of selected item in list box as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003095/getting-value-of-selected-item-in-list-box-as-string)

someone suggested -

```
String SelectedItem = listBox1.SelectedItem.Value
```

However, 'Value' is not an option when I try this.

How can I get the ValueMember value from a single selected item in a listbox?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`var text = (listBox1.SelectedItem as DataRowView)["columnName"].ToString();`

Replace `columnName` with the name of the column you want to get data from, which will correspond with a column in your datasource.

Also watch out for nulls if there's no selected item.

Comment: BeCareful!!  if you set datasource before setting display/valueMemmber .  you may get wrong values !!  . cuz `listbox.selectedIndexChanged` triggers right after you set Datasource.

Answer (score 6):

It really should be this easy; I have the following in a click event for button to make sure I wasn't over simplifying it in my head:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selected = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedValue);
        MessageBox.Show(selected);
    }
```

And the result:

[image]

---

### Edit

It looks like your issue may be from not setting a property on the control:

[image]

1. Select the ListBox control
2. Click the little arrow to show the binding / items options
3. Select **Use Data Bound Items**

If I deselect that box, I get the exact same behavior you are describing.

Comment: Thanks. But I believe you missed an important part of the question. I need the ValueMember value, not the tex.

Comment: For me, it only returns the text you see in the listbox, not the value assigned by the ValueMember.

Comment: If you select the listbox in the designer, then use the little arrow to see the items, is the checkbox for "Use Data Bound Items" checked?

Comment: @LeeLoftiss OK, I think I see what your getting the issue from then; updated.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
var selectedValue = listBoxTopics.SelectedItem;
if (selectedValue != null)
{ 
     MessageBox.Show(listBoxTopics.SelectedValue.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the DataValueField of the listbox.

```
NewEmployeesLB.DataSource = newEmployeesPersons.DataList.Select(np => new 
ListItem() { Text = np.LastName + ", " + np.FirstName, Value = np.PersonID.ToString() }).ToList();
            NewEmployeesLB.DataTextField = "Text";
            NewEmployeesLB.DataValueField = "Value";
            NewEmployeesLB.DataBind();
```