# 2 listviews working together

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have created an asp.net page with two listviews. one with a name and message date and one with the message in it When I click the first i would like to highlight the message in the other listview but I really don't know how to get this to work. I hope somone give me a hint here.

I have get the method like this from the first listview.

```
Protected Sub lswBerichten2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lswBerichten2.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim lblmsgid As Label = CType(lswBerichten2.Items(lswBerichten2.SelectedIndex).FindControl("msgid"), Label)
    HiddenMessageId.Value = lblmsgide.Text        

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not entirely sure what you are looking for, Im not sure the intent is entirely clear. However I do believe you are binding data to two lists (I assume the same datasource, just different fields), and when an item in list 1 is selected, the corresponding item in list 2 will be selected. Here is my take:

First the listboxes must have the data assigned; by binding the display and value differently, you can allow for the data ID field to be included.

```
listBox1.DataSource = YourDatasource;
listBox1.ValueMember = YourIDField;
listBox1.DisplayMember = YourMessageOverview;

listBox2.DataSource = YourDatasource;
listBox2.ValueMember = YourIDField;
listBox2.DisplayMember = YourMessageText;
```

Then when the selection is changed, establish what the ID of the selected item is, then search the second list for an item with the same value.

```
protected void listbox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string val = (listBox1.SelectedItem as DataRowView)["columnName"].ToString();
     listbox2.Items.FindByValue(val).Selected = true;
}
```

I have not checked this code, however I would assume that it should not have many issues.

Also I apologise for the C# response to a VB question, it has been years since I worked in VB.

Changed selected item value retrieval in accordance to this [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21717777/4210193), Hopefully that helps?

Comment: So if your binding with the messageID as the value, then the way described sounds like a likely possibility.

Comment: Hello Nickson,  Thanks I have tryed this, but there is no listbox1.SelectedItem.Value in aps.net this looks like the listbox for Windows forms. Is there a way to do this in asp.net?