# Getting the value of a selected item within a List box connected to a Sql Table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a listbox filled with data from a table within sql-server.  I am trying to find a way to click on an item within the listbox and then find the ID associated with the selected item.  I have been looking online for ways to do this and have tried methods from the following question within stack overflow but none of them seem to work for me
[Getting value of selected item in list box as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003095/getting-value-of-selected-item-in-list-box-as-string)

Here is how I fill my listbox with code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    String Sql = @" select * from project";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Resources.cString);
    SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(Sql, Properties.Resources.cString);
    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    DA.Fill(DS, "Project");
    DataTable DT = DS.Tables["Project"];

    lbProjects.DataValueField = "ProjectID";
    lbProjects.DataTextField = "ProjectName";
    lbProjects.DataSource = DT;
    lbProjects.DataBind();

}
```

The list box is filling with the correct data.  What I am trying to do is when an item is selected and a button is pressed then the selected value will be retrieved.  He is what I have attempted and it does not work

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
         String text = lbProjects.SelectedValue.ToString();      
}
```

Of course when I debug the selectedvalue is  " "

Is there a specific way to do this for listboxes connected to Sql? Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I have also used SelectedItem and that does not work

SQL TABLE CODE

```
    create TABLE PROJECT
(
ProjectID int Not Null,
ProjectName varchar (35) Not Null,
ProjectDesc varchar (100) Not Null,
ProjectStartDate VarChar (11)Not Null,
ProjectFinishedDate Varchar (11) Not Null,
SupportTeamID varchar(10) NOT NULL,
leadContact int NOT NULL,
leadDeveloper int NOT NULL,

Constraint pk_Project Primary Key (ProjectID),
Constraint fk_supportTeamID Foreign Key (supportTeamID) references supportTeam(supportTeamID)
)
```

Comment: You really should get in the habit of not using select * when you need 2 columns. And the save method makes me cry. You have an anti-pattern there I call try-squelch. You go through the hassle of catching an error to wrap it up and throw it in the trash. You need to either handle your error properly or stop having your code act like nothing is wrong. Errors happen, embrace it and make sure you deal with them.

Comment: For the task at hand, what is the SelectedIndex when your Save method executes? And how many items are in the list box?

Comment: Well I literally only started the form, its called the save button because I copied it from another form also what I plan to do is display all of the projects information depending on what has been selected within the listbox.  The try catch is there but doesn't make a difference that's there for future reference I am getting my results through debugging, honestly the try catch doesn't need to be there its just something I like to do.  There are 5 items within the listbox

Comment: My point on the try-catch is that you should never have an empty one. Of course handling errors is a great thing but an empty catch is a nightmare even during development. So again, when your code is executing the btnSave_Click method what is the value of lbProjects.Items.Count? And what is the value of lbProjects.SelectedIndex?

Comment: lbProjects.Items.Count = 5

Comment: lbProjects.SelectedIndex = -1

Comment: Have no idea why it is = to -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had nothing to do with my list box code, instead it was something to do with the post back. 
I added this to the page load and it now works

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
if(!IsPostBack)
{


String Sql = @" select * from project";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Resources.cString);
SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(Sql, Properties.Resources.cString);
DataSet DS = new DataSet();
DA.Fill(DS, "Project");
DataTable DT = DS.Tables["Project"];

lbProjects.DataValueField = "ProjectID";
lbProjects.DataTextField = "ProjectName";
lbProjects.DataSource = DT;
lbProjects.DataBind();
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `Selecteditem` property?

```
String text = lbProjects.SelectedItem;
```

Comment: Tried that sorry, get "Value" as an answer

Comment: What the column names in your project sql table?

Comment: Ill add them to the question

Comment: You would at the very least need to use .ToString. You can't set a string equal to a listbox item.