# c# textbox shows object name instead of value

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, listbox, listboxitem

I have a form written in c#, with various drop down lists, but I'm having problems with a listbox on the form.  I need to populate a textbox with the values selected from the listbox when I double click on them.  I've got the click event working, but the textbox will only populate with the object name, not the value from the listbox

i.e.

> 'System.Windows.Controls.SelectedItemCollection'

instead of the actual value.

Here is the entire code block I'm working on:

I should have just done this at the start - here is the complete code block I'm working on:

```
else if (theValue.FieldName.Equals("UIPathList", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true)
            {
                int nRow = 14;
                Button theUIPathOptionsButton = new Button();

                TextBox theOldValueTextBox = AddLabelAndOldValue(theHelper, nRow, theValue);
                theOldValueTextBox.Text = theValue.OldValue.Replace(",", "," + Environment.NewLine);

                theUIPathOuterStackPanel = new StackPanel
                {
                    Visibility = Visibility.Visible,
                    Orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
                    Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White),
                    ClipToBounds = true,
                };

                theUIPathOptionsInnerStackPanel = new StackPanel
                {
                    Visibility = Visibility.Visible,
                    Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
                    Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)
                };
                theUIPathOuterStackPanel.ClipToBounds = true;

                TextBox theNewTextBox = new TextBox
                {
                    TabIndex = nRow,
                    TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,
                    AcceptsReturn = true,
                };

                theNewTextBox.Clear();
                theNewTextBox.MouseDoubleClick += MultiLineChildDatapointList_HandleMouseDoubleClick;
                theNewTextBox.Focusable = true;
                theNewTextBox.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
                theNewTextBox.Width = 365;

                theNewTextBox.PreviewKeyDown += theGetMetadataHelper.Preview_KeyDown_IsMultilineText;

                theNewTextBox.Tag = theValue;

                ListBox theUIPathOptionslistBox = new ListBox();
                theUIPathOptionslistBox.Items.Add("RuntimeDefaults");
                theUIPathOptionslistBox.Items.Add("CommonSettings");
                theUIPathOptionslistBox.Items.Add(InputDatapointManager.CONST_CHANGE_RECORD_CHANGES_CLEAR_VALUE);
                theUIPathOptionslistBox.TabIndex = nRow;
                theUIPathOptionslistBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Multiple;
                theUIPathOptionslistBox.ClipToBounds = true;
                theUIPathOptionslistBox.Focusable = true;
                theUIPathOptionslistBox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                theUIPathOptionslistBox.Height = 34;

                theUIPathOptionsInnerStackPanel.Children.Add(theNewTextBox);
                theUIPathOptionsInnerStackPanel.Children.Add(theUIPathOptionsButton);

                theUIPathOuterStackPanel.Children.Add(theUIPathOptionsInnerStackPanel);
                theUIPathOuterStackPanel.Children.Add(theUIPathOptionslistBox);

                void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    theUIPathOptionslistBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }

                void button1_doubleclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    theNewTextBox.Text = theUIPathOptionslistBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
                }

                theUIPathOptionsButton.Click += button1_click;
                theUIPathOptionslistBox.MouseDoubleClick += button1_doubleclick;

                Grid.SetColumn(theUIPathOuterStackPanel, 4);
                Grid.SetRow(theUIPathOuterStackPanel, nRow);
                theDataGrid.Children.Add(theUIPathOuterStackPanel);

                theEditControlList.Add(theNewTextBox);
            }
```

Comment: you should share your code

Comment: It sounds like you're setting the text to an object rather than a text value.  Set it to the value you want.

Comment: The selected item is an `Object`. You will need to cast it to the Type it really is and assign the appropriate property of that Type to the textbox value.

Comment: void button1_doubleclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    theNewTextBox.Text = theOptionslistBox.SelectedItems.ToString();
                }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListBox, Item is a collection of objects, not strings, so you must let it know how to convert it to string, otherwise it will use its defualt `.ToString()` function that obviously the object currently in your items not giving the desired result.

Imagine items are oftype following class:

```
class SomeClass
{
      public int Id;
      public string Name;
}
```

You may do one of these three:

1.set the `DisplayMember` of your ListBox to `Name`

2.add override method to your class so that it overrides its `.ToString()` and return its Name property:

```
class SomeClass
{
      public int Id;
      public string Name;

      public override string ToString()
      {
            return Name;
      }
}
```

3.Just cast it to its real type and get the property you want:

```
SomeClass selected = (SomeClass)ListBox.SelectedItem;
TextBox1.Text = selected.Name;
```

Comment: sorry for the noob questions, but when I try to create the class, I start getting errors from all my other controls etc - where would I put this class exactly?  I feel this is complicated further because this block of code is in an else piece of a humongous if statement

Comment: Sorry for late answer, you don't need to create a class, I was setting an example of what the listbox current input is like (its something like a class that i mentioned) to get a much better answer, you should post your code, indeed if you had posted your code and we know where (exact code of items) items come from, you would have received many good answers in minues

Comment: which part you have problem with?

Comment: Hi Ashkan - would it help if I mentioned that this is in WPF and not winforms?

Comment: thanks so much for your help.  I've downloaded the file so you can delete the comment.

Comment: Sorry to sound ungrateful, but what I'm trying to do is use a wpf ListBox that allows multiple selections, and takes those selections and populates the textbox.  I have it working but just for a single selection (using the SelectionChanged event) but can't get it to work with multiple selections - any ideas?  Here is my code:

Comment: void theUIPathOptionslistBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
                {
                    object listBoxItemSelectionChanged = theUIPathOptionslistBox.SelectedItem;

                    if (listBoxItemSelectionChanged == null)
                    {
                        theNewTextBox.Text = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        theNewTextBox.Text = listBoxItemSelectionChanged.ToString();
                    }
                }

Comment: sorry to be a pain, but can you take a look at why the code below is preventing the text that went from the ListBox to the TextBox being accepted?  In the previous version of this app, the textbox was freeform and the user just typed in the value they wanted, but now when I populate the TextBox with the ListBox selecteditems it seems to just not accept it anymore.

Comment: else if (theDatapointFieldName.Equals("UIPathList", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true)
                    {
                        CheckChangedListOfStringNoValidation(pi.GetValue(Datapoint) as List<string>, theDatapointFieldName, (theControl as TextBox).Text.Trim(), theChange);
                    }

Answer (score 1):

This was (possibly) already answered here : [Getting value of selected item in list box as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003095/getting-value-of-selected-item-in-list-box-as-string)

```
string myItem = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);
```

Then you just have to add your item to the textbox :

```
textBox1.Text = myItem;
```

If you don't want to create a new string variable, then this one is working too :

```
textBox1.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Comment: When I try to use 'GetItemText' VS is telling me "ListBox does not contain a definition for 'GetItemText' - is there a particular using statement I need to bring in?

Comment: `using System.Windows.Forms` is all you need. Just tested the following line : `textBox1.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();` and it works too.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the context of this form I can't use Windows.Forms - it messes with all the other controls, textboxes, etc on the form.  Thanks though!

Comment: Also, I can't use the 'textBox1.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();' suggestion - that's what I have been using and doesn't show the text of the items selected - trying to implement the override that's been suggested but it's messing with other controls etc on this form...

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `TextBox` will use the `ToString()` method on what it is bound to, which by default will return the class name.

You solutions are to either override the `ToString()` method of the class to return the value you want or set the text property of the `TextBox` to the text value you want rather then the object.

Comment: do you mean like this:  theNewTextBox.Text = "value I want to appear"?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I finally got to was as follows:

```
void theUIPathOptionslistBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, 
SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    theNewTextBox.Clear();
    foreach (object selectedItem in theUIPathOptionslistBox.SelectedItems)
    {
        theNewTextBox.AppendText(selectedItem.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
theUIPathOptionslistBox.SelectionChanged += 
theUIPathOptionslistBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
```